# Add to Laravel query using callable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to add to a Laravel query using a callable.

For example, I have a string for sorting records. Based on this string, I want to add to my query via an array:

```
public $sort = 'Newest';

public function sortQuery(Builder $query)
{
    return [
        'Name' => $query->orderBy('name'),
        'Newest' => $query->orderBy('created_at'),
        'Oldest' => $query->orderByDesc('created_at'),
    ];
}

public function paginateQuery()
{
    $query = User::query();

    foreach ($this->sortQuery($query) as $key => $value) {
        if ($this->sort == $key) {
            $query = $value;
        }
    }

    return $query->paginate();
}
```

In this example, when I run `$this->paginateQuery()` it does not sort as desired.

I've also tried `$query = $this->sortQuery($query)[$this->sort];` instead of the `foreach` loop and the result is the same.

How would I chain `$value` onto the `$query` based on the array key?

Answer (score 1):

You can amend your function slightly to apply the sorting immediately, for instance like so:

```php
public function sortQuery(Builder $query, $sortKeys)
{
    // Define a map to find the options for your specific sorting key.
    $map = [ 
        'Name' => ['name', 'ASC'],
        // Note: I flipped this around, Newest first means "descending date".
        'Newest' => ['created_at', 'DESC'],
        'Oldest' => ['created_at', 'ASC'],        
    ];

    // Loop the given sortkeys. The (array) cast allows you to pass a string as well.
    foreach((array) $sortKeys as $sortKey) {
        // Check if map exists.
        if(isset($map[$sortKey])) {
            // Use the splat operator to pass the map values as arguments to the orderBy function
            // (the second argument can be ASC/DESC)
            $query->orderBy(...$map[$sortKey]);
         
    }
}
```

You can even define it as a query scope in one of your models (preferably a parent class that is inherited by multiple Eloquent models), see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes:

```php
// Model.php
/**
 * The prefix `scope` is required. It can be called as `$query->sortMe(...)`.
 */
public function scopeSortMe(Builder $query, $sortKeys)
{
    // ... same code
}
// SomeController.php
// Calling it only requires the additional parameters, not the $query object.
$query->sortMe($sortKeys);
```